# how to get map database of a certain city?

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, openstreetmap

Does anyone know how and where to get/purchase map database of a certain city that we can access coordinate of streets, points of interest, so on....
I have the task of visualizing maps offline.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can download OpenStreetMap data for specific cities directly from [download.geofabrik.de](http://download.geofabrik.de). That's easy.

Then you just need to get acquainted with the [data elements in OSM data](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements). It's all very simple, and the elements are represented very straightforwardly in OSM's XML format.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to render map from OSM data using **TileMill**, [here](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/create-a-custom-map-of-your-city-in-30-minutes-with-tilemill-and-openstreetmap/) is tutorial how to do this. There are extracts for lots of cities on [metro.teczno.com](http://metro.teczno.com/).